# Ansible MySQL User with REQUIRE SSL

Tags: mysql, configuration-management, ansible

I've just begun learning Ansible today, and I'm already making fast progress and on the edge of being able to automate our whole IT stack. That's nice! :)

I've however hit a roadblock. We've chosen to take the small performance hit and encrypt ALL MySQL connections using the SSL feature. This is to let our office IP's remotely manage it, and also inter-datacenter.

Using the mysql_user module, I can make sure an user is added, and set the password and so forth. But I can't seem to find anyway to require SSL on the user? According to a quick Google, and the lack of options in the documentation, I guess I can't do it with mysql_user.

But the real question is: **Do you know a (preferably clean) work around?**

If I could somehow execute raw queries with Ansible it would be perfect. To be specific, I need to replicate this SQL in Ansible, however possible:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘ssluser’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘pass’ REQUIRE SSL;
```

Comment: I know SSL is still possible without the REQUIRE SSL statement, but I would just like to enforce it, so no "new guy" (or tired me) ever connects to the server without SSL, and if it's done somewhere I would like an immediate connection error, so I know something is wrong. That's why I want to enforce it.

Comment: This does not directly answer your question, but instead of exposing MySQL to the internet(even if it's ssl'ed), consider having it listen only on `127.0.0.1` and then use SSH tunnel for remote administration.

Comment: Thanks @Mxx I've thought about that. I honestly just liked the simplicity while still retaining security. The server is firewalled to office IP only, so I don't see it as a big concern. I just wanted to protect data while in transit from casual sys-admin observers and such on our ISP. I might do it in the future tho as it feels "dirty" to have an exposed MySQL server even through only to a specific IP.

Comment: With SSH those casual observers won't even know that you have mysql traffic going there since everything will be encapsulated in SSH. To setup an SSH tunnel is just a single command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me, without the `append_privs` option (ansible 2+)

```
priv='some_db.*:ALL,GRANT,REQUIRESSL'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this with the mysql_user module:

```
- mysql_user: name=bob password=12345 append_privs=*.*:REQUIRESSL
```

By using "append_privs" you'd just be adding "REQUIRE SSL" to the existing privileges for bob.

If you want to do this manually it can get a little ugly, but you can always invoke the mysql client via the command module.  Assuming you have variables defined for the mysql user & host:

```
- command: mysql -u {{ myslq_user }} -h {{ mysql_host }} -p{{ mysql_password }} "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘ssluser’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘pass’ REQUIRE SSL;"
```

Edit: I just ran some tests and got this to work without any problems after ensuring that [the proper Python libraries](http://docs.ansible.com/mysql_user_module.html) were installed:

```
- hosts: myhost
  name: test
  user: my-user
  tasks:
    - local_action: mysql_user
                    user=foo
                    host='%'
                    password=bar
                    state=present
                    append_privs=yes
                    login_host=<my_database_host>
                    login_user=<my_database_root_user>
                    login_password=<my_database_root_password>
                    priv='*.*:REQUIRESSL'
```

The above resulted in:

```
mysql> show grants for 'foo'@'%';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@%                                                                                               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E8D46CE25265E545D225A8A6F1BAF642FEBEE5CB' REQUIRE SSL |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hmm I tried the append_privs way, but get an error "msg: Boolean *.*:require ssl not in either boolean list" so I don't think it works since it is not a mysql "priv_type"

Comment: Interesting.  I took a look at the source of the mysql module and there are references to "require ssl" that seems to imply this would have worked.  If I have time next week I'll see if I can figure it out...